# The result from release is different from debugging

Tags: c++

So, I was using VScode to run my c++.
Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    int value = 153;
    int output=0;
    string number = to_string(value);
    int exp = number.length();
    for (char n :number) output += pow(n-'0',exp);  
    cout << output;
}
```

The output I get from using "Run Code" is 152, which is wrong. The output from using debug is 153,which is right. Why would that happen?

Comment: Is it possible the floating point settings are different between your release and debug builds, like is fast math turned on in release? `ceil(pow(n-'0',exp))` might help.

Comment: This feels a lot like a very tiny rounding error. What are you trying to do here? Using `pow` to do string to number conversion is not the fastest way to do this.

Comment: This may help: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I was doing a codewars question which is Narcissistic Number.  `ceil(pow(n-'0'), exp) `is working, thanks!

Comment: @totoma -- Advice -- Do not use floating point functions such as `pow` to do non-floating point solutions.  If the goal of the program was to turn 153 into a string or from a string to an integer, there is no need to use `pow` for that -- just a simple modulus of 10 and repeated integer division or multiplication.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  yeah, thanks a lot. The goal is to tell if a number is a positive number which is the sum of its own digits, each raised to the power of the number of digits. I was testing the main part.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to convert the number to a string? If you need to print the digits one by one (in the correct order) there are many other ways.

Comment: string.length() returns a size_t (not an int).   you also should check inputs/output to pow (does not return an int to add to output) and ceil (does not return an int for exp).